# How to structure a website with custom post types and custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am building a website for a sports club where you can practice multiple sports:

- Football
- Handball
- Volleybal
- Tennis

Each sport can have teams. The teams are categorized as:

- Senior

  - Men
  - Ladies
- Junior

  - Boys
  - Girls

I want the permalink structure to be like:

```
http://www.example.com/{sport-name}/{category}/{category}/{team-name}
```

example: `http://www.example.com/football/senior/men/first-team`

I was thinking about adding 'teams' as a custom post type and a custom taxonomy to categorize the teams. But I don't think this setup will help me achieve this.

How can I set WordPress up to get the permalink that I want?

Comment: Do you dream about comfortable information structure (and navigation) or how do kilometer-long permalinks look like?

[Custom WordPress Rewrite Rule to Combine Taxonomy and Post Type](https://www.ibenic.com/custom-wordpress-rewrite-rule-combine-taxonomy-post-type/) is enough to start.

Answer (score 0):

What would actually be the content of such a page as 
`http://www.example.com/{sport-name}/{category}/{category}/{team-name}`? I can conceive of a team roster and statistics page, but only for a professional team. A sports club would be more geared toward needing to see the league schedule (time and location of next game), and perhaps win/loss record to feed into the playoff computation.

Do you really need a CPT? Are you coding some functionality to go into it? If not, just use pages to show the various sports, their schedules, costs, rules, and contact info for signing up. Then each category can have a page for the current league's game schedule and it will be easy to update with the win/loss results after each game day.